# What's the pythonic way of passing on default arguments?

Tags: python

I've been wondering about this for a while. If I have a function with a default argument, and that function is called by another function which needs to pass on said argument. Now that function would also need to set a default. How can I avoid copy-pasting the default value?

Example code:

```
def foo(a=3):
    print(a)
    
def bar(it=10, a=3):
    for i in range(it):
        foo(a=a)
```

How do I avoid having to set the default value for a second time?

I can think of perhaps doing it with argv like:

```
def foo(a=3):
    print(a)
    
def bar(it=10, *argv):
    for i in range(it):
        foo(*argv)
```

But aside from me not liking it (it doesn't play well with code completion) that only works if there is only a single function whose default parameters I want to pass on. It doesn't work if there are two or more.

The other option would be completely restructuring the code, perhaps passing on a partial application of foo, like:

```
def foo(a=3):
    print(a)

def bar(pfoo, it=10):
    for i in range(it):
        pfoo()

bar(pfoo=foo) # if I want to use the default
bar(pfoo=lambda: foo(a=5)) # if I want a different value for a
```

But depending on the specific use case, this feels a bit overengineered (and perhaps hard to read) to me.

My "dreamcode" would be something like:

```
def foo(a=3):
   print(a)

def bar(it=10, a=foo.defaults.a):
   for i in range(it):
       foo(a=a)
```

I noticed there are `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` dunders, but the former is a tuple and not named, so I would have to make sure I get the order right (which is a major source of error), and the latter is only filled if there is a `*` argument in foo, that would otherwise swallow all the other arguments. Hence if I want to use those dunders I have to change it to:

```
def foo(*, a=3):
    print(a)

def bar(it=10, a=foo.__kwdefaults__['a']):
    for i in range(it):
        foo(a=a)
```

But I don't really want foo to accept arbitrary arguments...

How do you guys deal with this?

Comment: The first one is the most pythonic

Comment: Would you recommend storing "constants" somewhere, in order to avoid having to propagate changes to defaults up the calling tree (and potentially missing some)?

Comment: Perhaps. Alternatively you could use a class

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. If you want to use the defaults, don't specify them lower down in the calling tree.

Comment: Hm, but I want both functions to have the same default, yet still retain the ability to be called with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, if you just want to call `foo()` from `bar()` with the same default parameter of a=3, then you don't need to assign any value to a:

```
def foo(a=3):
    print(a)
    
def bar(it=10):
    for i in range(it):
        foo()
```

This will call foo, and assign the default value of 3 to the parameter a

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I still want to give a caller of ```bar``` the ability to provide a different ```a```. I want bar and foo to have the same defaults, but I want both to still expose the parameter ```a``` to the caller.

Comment: In response to your comment, you could try having the default parameters stored as a kwarg dictionary:

```foo_bar_params = {'a': 3, 'b': 7, ...}```

and then call that in for bar:

```def bar(it=10, **foo_bar_dict): ... foo(**foo_bar_dict)```

Comment: Hm, yeah, that's better than my ```argv``` solution, but I'm still a bit dissatisfied. It means that one cannot determine the arguments ```bar``` takes by looking at at the signature of ```bar```. On the other hand, it's more flexible than even my "dream solution" (form my post) because it means the arguments of ```bar``` automatically get expanded when the arguments of ```foo``` do.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specify `foo`'s default as the default value of `bar's` parameter, use a sentinel value that indicates whether you want to call `foo` with an explicit argument or not.

```
from functools import partial


use_foo_default = object()

def bar(it=10, a=use_foo_default):  
    f = foo if a is use_foo_default else partial(foo, a)
    for i in range(it):
        f()
```

(If you know that `foo` can't take `None` as a valid argument, you can use `None` in place of the explicitly declared sentinel shown here.)